# Getting data from access to combobox not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get data from access to a `combobox1` but its not working.

my database is a `.accdb` file. my table name is "list".

the columns names are:

> "ID_lista" = autonumber
>
> "Nome" = smalltext
>
> "Link" = hyperlink

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace teste_pwd
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static class Globals
        {
            public static String ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\PWD_BD.accdb";
            public static OleDbConnection ConnectionString = new OleDbConnection(Globals.ConString);
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Globals.ConnectionString.Close();
            pCMB();

        }

        public void pCMB() 
        {
            try
            {
                
                Globals.ConnectionString.Open();

                int i = 0;

                string query = "SELECT * FROM List";

                OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapeter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, Globals.ConnectionString);
                DataSet mydata = new DataSet();


                dataAdapeter.Fill(mydata, "List");
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Texto";
                comboBox1.ValueMember = "Valor";
                DataTable tb = new DataTable();
                tb.Columns.Add("Texto", typeof(string));
                tb.Columns.Add("Valor", typeof(int));

                for (i = 0; i <= mydata.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    tb.Rows.Add(mydata.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[1], mydata.Tables[0].Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);

                }
                comboBox1.DataSource = tb;

                Globals.ConnectionString.Close();



            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on the _not working_ part? What is not working?

Comment: Maybe you need to change table name because it reserved word, but please clarify the error message and what happenend  exactly

Comment: there is no error messege.. it just dosent show the content

Answer (score 0):

this code might help you to add data to combo box.
this code is for vb.net

```
        Dim DrContractor As DataRow
        Dim DtContractor As DataTable
        Dim i As Integer

        strQuery = " SELECT * FROM CONTRACTOR ORDER BY CONTCODE"
        Dim DataAdapeter As New SqlDataAdapter(strQuery, myConnection)
        Dim dsDivision As New DataSet
        'myConnection.Open()
        DataAdapeter.Fill(dsDivision, "CONTRACTOR")

        DtContractor = dsDivision.Tables("CONTRACTOR")

        'myConnection.Close()
        cboContractor.Items.Add("ALL")
        For i = 0 To DtContractor.Rows.Count - 1
            DrContractor = DtContractor.Rows(i)
            cboContractor.Items.Add(DrContractor("CONTNAME").ToString & " : " & DrContractor("CONTCODE").ToString)
        Next
        cboContractor.SelectedIndex = 0
        cboContractor.SelectedText = ""
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```